# stateless component not rendering after mapping over array passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have refactored my code and now have a stateless component that gets passed an array from a container component. I then try and map over the array passed into my stateless component but can not get it to render.

The array is being passed in correctly, but when I `console.log(msg)` it just shows the first `msg` and nothing gets rendered.

Can anyone spot what is wrong with the code below?

```
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const { getData } = this.props;
        getData();
    }

    render() {
        const { messages } = this.props;

        return (
            <ul>
                <MessageList messages={messages} />
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {
        messages: state.messages ? state.messages : [],
        members: state.members ? state.members : []
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({ getChatLog, getMembersData }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I then have a `MessageList` stateless component that looks like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import Message from './Message';

const MessageList = ({messages, members}) => {

    let getMemberDetails = (userId) => {
        return members.find(member => member.id === userId);
    }

    let sortMessagesByDate = (messages) => {
        return (messages && messages.length > 0) ? messages.sort((a, b) => {
            return moment(b.timestamp) - moment(a.timestamp);
        }) : [];
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {sortMessagesByDate(messages).map(msg => {

               let member = getMemberDetails(msg.userId);
               let time = moment(msg.timestamp).format('DD-MM-YY');
               let name = `${member.firstName} ${member.lastName}`;

                return(
                    <div className="messages-container" key={msg.id}>
                        <img alt="avatar" src={msg.avatar } />
                        <Message msg={msg} name={name} time={time} />
                    </div>
                );
            })
        }   
        </div>
    );
}


export default MessageList;
```

Comment: Are you sure `messages` is not empty?

Comment: And what triggers the rerender after the data was fetched? I can only assume that you are not handling the fetching correctly and that the component is not updated. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: its is empty at the start, but then after it is fetched it contains 100 objects. the data comes from the redux store. mapStateToProps should rerender app when data is received, no?  I should prob include that in the question too. I dont think that is the issue, so i left it out, althought I am PROBABLY wrong

Comment: Yes, if you are using redux than it should probably work as expected, but impossible to tell without a complete example.

Comment: @FelixKling oh for god sake, it was because I was only passing in `messages`,  but not `members`.  Sloppy of me, but prob should be an error , no?

Comment: Well, you are not accessing `member` anywhere, so that's not an issue. But  `<Message msg={msg} name={name} time={time} />` looks fishy. `name` and `time` are not defined. That would throw an error.

Comment: @FelixKling actually they are all being used, but I simplified the component for teh question. I will add the full code now and you can see as it isnt much longer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153714/discussion-between-raul-rodriguez-and-felix-kling).

Comment: `members` is undefined.

Comment: @Prakashsharma thanks, you are correct, I actually figured that out, but issue is, at least as far as I can tell no error/warning was shown in the console